# React JS components rerendering despite callbacks when props are passed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback

In my react project, I set up callbacks to stop excessive re-renderings, because the data displayed there is fairly large, and there are a lot of different buttons that the user can click, all which would cause rerenderings.

The useCallback hooks work, and no rerenderings are called, unless I am also passing in props alongside the useCallback functions, in which case the child component is rerendered every time the user interacts with the app.

So for instance, if I create a child component like so :

```
<Dropdown
//props={{ cat, var }}
getLi={getLi}
getType={getType}
increment={increment}
/>
```

And inside the dropdown child I define cat and var as `const cat = ""` and `const var = "10"`

Then the component does not get rerendered when I click on the dropdown menu buttons inside the child component.

However, if I create the child component like this -

```
<Dropdown
props={{ cat, var }}
getLi={getLi}
getType={getType}
increment={increment}
/>
```

And then define cat and var as `const {cat, var} = props`

The callback functions do not work, and the childcomponent gets rerendered constantly.

I tried adding both of the variables in props to the list of dependancies in the callback function, which also did nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
props={{ cat, var }}
```

Every time this runs, it creates a new object. The object may have the same keys and values, but it's a new object. If you're using React.memo on the `Dropdown`, then it's going to do a === between the old object and the new object, see that they're different, and thus rerender.

If you want to skip renders, you need to make sure all your props pass a === check. So you can either memoize this object:

```
const example = useMemo(() => {
  return { cat, var }
}, [cat, var])

// ...
<Dropdown
  props={example}
```

Or split it into separate props, so each of them will have its own === check.

```
<Dropdown
  cat={cat}
  var={var}
  getLi={getLi}
  // ...
```